# Show current Git commit ID (hash) as defaultValue on an input form in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In the `Jenkinsfile` below, I would like to show the current git commit id (hash) as a default value on an input form in Jenkins:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Doit!') {
      input {
        message "Begin?"
        parameters {
          string(name: 'commitID', description: 'Commit ID', defaultValue: "${env.GIT_COMMIT}")
          string(name: 'buildNum', description: 'Build Number', defaultValue: "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh "echo commitId ${commitID}"
        sh "echo buildNum ${buildNum}"
        sh "env"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As stated on the Git Plugin documentation, the git commit id is set on a environment variable named `GIT_COMMIT`, however the input form does not show its value (even though it shows the variable BUILD_NUMBER, for example.)

[image: Jenkins input form with null value in commitId field]

Please note that the `GIT_COMMIT` and `BUILD_NUMBER` show up on `sh "env"` step.

[image: BUILD_NUMBER environment variable correctly printed out]

[image: GIT_COMMIT environment variable correctly printed out]

---

**Edit:**

I also tried to skip the default checkout and do it in a explicit pipeline step, to no avail.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        checkout scm
      }
    }
    stage('Doit!') {
      input {
        message "Begin?"
        parameters {
          string(name: 'commitID', description: 'Commit ID', defaultValue: "${env.GIT_COMMIT}")
          string(name: 'buildNum', description: 'Build Number', defaultValue: "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
        }
      }
      steps {
        sh "echo commitId ${commitID}"
        sh "echo buildNum ${buildNum}"
        sh "env"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where/how do you clone the repository? Cant find that in your snippet.

Comment: @JoergS I edited the question to include a second try that skips the default checkout and performs the check out in a regular step

Comment: The repository information is in the pipeline configuration in Jenkins (and not in the Jenkinsfile.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why it show null, it may be related to the fact input directive is executed before entering in the stage's agent ?

As a workaround you could do

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages {
     stage('Doit!') {
         steps {
            script {
                val = input message : "Continue the pipeline? ${env.GIT_COMMIT}", 
                           parameters: [
                                string(name: 'commitID', description: 'Commit ID', defaultValue: "${env.GIT_COMMIT}"),
                                string(name: 'buildNum', description: 'Build Number', defaultValue: "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
                           ]
               env.buildNum = val.buildNum
               env.commitID = val.commitID
           }
           print "Commit ID ${commitID}"
           print "buildNum ${buildNum}"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Note [it's not recommended](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/top-10-best-practices-jenkins-pipeline-plugin) to use an input inside a node because it lock the executor.

Comment: Your workaround seems to work but it has this locking problem you stated.

Comment: Yes, it's a problem depending on the number of possible current job running. Another way would be: does the person running the pipeline **need** to see the hash ? If not you could just leave a tip like _default will be the last commit_, leave the input outside the steps and in the deal with the default value inside.